# What permission is needed to view Database Diagrams through SSMS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Logged in as the DBO I create a database diagram in the Database Diagrams folder. Then I log in with only read permissions on the database and I can't see the diagram in the folder. What permission(s) do I need to be able to read the diagram, no edit?

[image]

This User can't see the database diagram:
[image]

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43946/permission-required-to-view-a-database-diagram ?

Comment: Not related, but my first instinct was to say, "But database diagrams are deprecated," so I Googled that. Turns out they were, but only for a few months, and now they're back. So +1 for helping me stay current.

Comment: @EricBrandt Yay us!